# Activity Leak? - Android

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, android-fragments, rotation

Activity leak is the most specific term I can come up with for my current problem. If it turns up to be something else, please correct me.

Scenario: I created a simple Android test app to produce my problem. I have an activity, a fragment that is added to the fragment container, and a separate thread that obtains data from a source (in the test app, it just creates the data itself) and relays it to the activity via the LocalBroadcastManager, where the activity, in turn, uses the data to update fragment being displayed.
Note: I am using the android-support-v7-appcompat, support-v4 fragments, API18, on a Nexus 4.

Problem: When the app is first started, everything runs as it should (At this point the "something  weird" being sent to logcat is normal).  The problem starts occurring after a rotation, a configuration change.  After rotation, the "something weird" should still be popping up by itself; however, it does not.  After rotation, the activity detects a null fragment and sets my debug flag; after which, the "something weird" should never reappear and only "null frag" or "frag there" should appear. And thus, my problem and confusion. 
Note: the more rotation you do, the more "null frag" statements you get for every "something weird" statement.

Here is the code you need to recreate the problem:

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.myfragthreadtest;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public static final String DEBUG_TAG = "MainActivity";
    public static final String OUTPUT_FRAGMENT = "OUTPUT_FRAGMENT";
    public static final String SAVED_DATA = "SAVED_DATA";

    public static final String UPDATE_SENT = "UPDATE_SENT";
    public static final String UPDATE_DATA = "UPDATE_DATA";

    private int myData;
    private MyFragment outputFrag;
    private volatile boolean debugFragFlag = false;
    private MyThread myThread;

    // Create a BroadcastReceiver for updates
    private final BroadcastReceiver uiUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // Check action
            if(UPDATE_SENT.equals(action)) {
                myData = intent.getIntExtra(UPDATE_DATA, -1);
                if(myData == -1) {
                    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "uiUpdateReceiver: data == -1");
                    return;
                }
                updateUI(myData);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myData = -2;
        myThread = null;

        // Register broadcast receivers
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
                             .registerReceiver(uiUpdateReceiver,
                                               new IntentFilter(UPDATE_SENT));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if(findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
            outputFrag = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                                      .findFragmentByTag(OUTPUT_FRAGMENT);
            if(outputFrag != null) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onStart: frag is there");
                return;
            }
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onStart: frag is not there");
            // Create new fragment and transaction
            outputFrag = new MyFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment
            transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, outputFrag, OUTPUT_FRAGMENT);
            transaction.commit();
        }
        else {
            Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "onCreate: No fragment container");
        }

        return;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        myData = savedInstanceState.getInt(SAVED_DATA);
        outputFrag = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(OUTPUT_FRAGMENT);
        if(outputFrag == null) {
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "updateUI: null frag");
            debugFragFlag = true;
            return;
        }
        outputFrag.updateOutput(myData);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        myThread = new MyThread(this, myData);
        myThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putInt(SAVED_DATA, myData);

        return;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // close out the data thread
        myThread.close();

        return;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private void updateUI(int data) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Update UI
                outputFrag = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                                          .findFragmentByTag(OUTPUT_FRAGMENT);
                if(outputFrag == null) {
                    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "updateUI: null frag");
                    debugFragFlag = true;
                    return;
                }
                else if(debugFragFlag) {
                    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "updateUI: frag there");
                }
                else {
                    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "updateUI: something weird");
                }
                outputFrag.updateOutput(myData);
            }
        });

        return;
    }
}
```

MyFragment.java:

```
package com.example.myfragthreadtest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "MyFragment";

    // UI components for updating
    private TextView console;
    private ScrollView consoleScroller;

    public void updateOutput(int data) {
        // Update UI
        setConsoleText(data);

        return;
    }

    private void setConsoleText(int data) {
        // Check that we have the UI components we want to update
        if(console == null || consoleScroller == null) {
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "setConsoleText: null views");
            return;
        }

        // Update UI
        console.setText("Data" + data);
        console.invalidate();

        consoleScroller.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        consoleScroller.invalidate();
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        console = null;
        consoleScroller = null;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_layout, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // Get UI components for updating
        console = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.output_console);
        consoleScroller = (ScrollView)getView().findViewById(R.id.console_scroller);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();  // Always call the superclass

        console = null;
        consoleScroller = null;

        return;
    }
}
```

MyThread.java:

```
package com.example.myfragthreadtest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyThread extends Thread {
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "MyThread";

    private Context appContext;
    private volatile boolean run;
    private int counter;

    public MyThread(Context context) {
        this.appContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        this.run = false;
        this.counter = 0;
    }

    public MyThread(Context context, int data) {
        this.appContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        this.run = false;
        this.counter = data;
    }

    public void run() {
        run = true;

        // Keep adding 1 every second
        while (run) {
            // Send update to the UI activity
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(MainActivity.UPDATE_SENT);
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.UPDATE_DATA, counter++);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(appContext).sendBroadcastSync(intent);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "run: Sleep Failed.");
            }
        }

        return;
    }

    // Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection 
    public void close() {
        run = false;
        return;
    }
}
```

frag_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/console_scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/output_console"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:textSize="25sp" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

here is the logcat output I am seeing:
Before rotation:

```
10-17 09:47:24.885: D/MainActivity(23085): onStart: frag is not there
10-17 09:47:24.905: E/MainActivity(23085): updateUI: something weird
10-17 09:47:24.935: D/libEGL(23085): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
10-17 09:47:24.945: D/libEGL(23085): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
10-17 09:47:24.945: D/libEGL(23085): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
10-17 09:47:24.945: I/Adreno200-EGL(23085): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:265>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: Iabe52cfaeae4c5fab1acacfe6f056ba15fa93274
10-17 09:47:24.985: D/OpenGLRenderer(23085): Enabling debug mode 0
10-17 09:47:27.898: D/MainActivity(23085): uiUpdateReceiver: data == -1
10-17 09:47:30.891: E/MainActivity(23085): updateUI: something weird
10-17 09:47:33.894: E/MainActivity(23085): updateUI: something weird
10-17 09:47:36.897: E/MainActivity(23085): updateUI: something weird
```

After rotation:

```
10-17 09:47:37.018: D/MainActivity(23085): onStart: frag is there
10-17 09:47:37.038: D/MainActivity(23085): updateUI: null frag
10-17 09:47:37.038: E/MainActivity(23085): updateUI: something weird
10-17 09:47:40.011: D/MainActivity(23085): updateUI: null frag
10-17 09:47:40.011: E/MainActivity(23085): updateUI: something weird
10-17 09:47:43.014: D/MainActivity(23085): updateUI: null frag
10-17 09:47:43.014: E/MainActivity(23085): updateUI: something weird
10-17 09:47:46.017: D/MainActivity(23085): updateUI: null frag
10-17 09:47:46.017: E/MainActivity(23085): updateUI: something weird
```

Even though everything seems fine just looking at the app, if someone rotates too much, I think this could cause issues.

Comment: You're retrieving your fragment in 3 different parts of your activity's lifecycle. I'd start with that. simply retrieve your fragment once in onCreate.

Comment: That did seem to solve the main issue (another issue arose after, but I won't go into that here). Do you have any reasoning as to why retrieving it more than once is bad? It is my understanding that I am still retrieving the same fragment and overwriting the same reference, so it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer my own question just for the rare occasion someone else reads this.

The problem was actually in the broadcaster. I never unregistered it. By adding:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance().unregisterReceiver(uiUpdateReceiver);
```

in the `OnDestroy()` method.

Somehow, I suppose, the receiver kept a reference to it's necessary objects/methods.